# TFS Build 2015 - How to copy a file's content to another one during the build?

Tags: c#, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm working in a project that has these two files

```
Web.env1.config
Web.env2.config
```

Those files represent the two different enviroments on which my application is published.

We're using TFS Build 2015 to publish our applications, and whenever I have to publish the application, I have to manually copy the content of the one of those files and paste it into `Web.config` file.

So, I wanted to know if it's possible to do this process automatically without having to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I do.

If all of your settings are located in config sections supported by it, you could [create transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) and apply them during a web deploy task in the release pipeline with this setting:

[image]

If I have environment-specific settings in sections not support by transforms, I maintain a `Web.config.template` file side-by-side with `web.config`. The environment-specific values are tokens that will be replaced in the Release Pipeline. For instance, instead of a connection string value it might be "~connstr~". `Web.config` is just used during debugging.

In the release pipeline I have a [replace tokens task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) that pulls pipeline variables and replaces the ~tokens~ with values. The environment-specific values are scoped pipeline variables:

[image]

After the `web.config.template` file has had it's tokens replaced with environment-specific values, I have a command line task that renames it to `web.config`. From there the pipeline deploys the files.

Another option is to create a [Secure File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops)  for each environment and bring it into the build or release pipeline.

Pipelines are very powerful and you can get creative with solutions.

Comment: I appreciate your answer I'll see if it solves my problem.